# Can I pull DISTINCT customers with SQL based on most recent row record only?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql, database

So, I have a data extension where data is being saved.

My data extension (CustomerSourceDE) looks something like this:

---

Id (text) NULLABLE

Email (Email) NULLABLE

Customer_FirstName (Text) NULLABLE

Status (Text) NULLABLE

RecordTimestamp (Date) default value - CURRENT DATETIME

---

Records in this data extension looks like this (one customer MAY have multiple rows which is why no primary key is defined)

---

1 | test1@test.com | Michael | New | Sunday, July 15, 2018 10:08 PM

2 | test2@test.com | Jackson | New | Sunday, July 15, 2018 10:10 PM

3 | test3@test.com | JordanAB | Accepted | Sunday, July 15, 2018 10:15 PM

1 | test1@test.com | Michael | Rejected | Sunday, July 15, 2018 10:25 PM

7 | test7@test.com | RobertMM | Rejected | Sunday, July 15, 2018 10:31 PM

2 | test2@test.com | Jackson | Disabled | Sunday, July 15, 2018 10:38 PM

---

In my Target Data Extension, I want DISTINCT records only and if there are multiple rows of same Id then I want most recent record row only based on the field (RecordTimestamp).

I have created this query but now getting the desired result (for some reason, I am getting 1 single record).

My desired result is this that I want in a new target data extension (MyTargetDE):

---

3 | test3@test.com | JordanAB | Accepted | Sunday, July 15, 2018 10:15 PM

1 | test1@test.com | Michael | Rejected | Sunday, July 15, 2018 10:25 PM

7 | test7@test.com | RobertMM | Rejected | Sunday, July 15, 2018 10:31 PM

2 | test2@test.com | Jackson | Disabled | Sunday, July 15, 2018 10:38 PM

---

My sql query which is NOT working and I need help with:

```
SELECT * FROM CustomerSourceDE
WHERE
Id IN (SELECT DISTINCT Id from CustomerSourceDE where AddRecordTimestamp =  (SELECT MAX(RecordTimestamp) FROM CustomerSourceDE as t WHERE Id = t.Id))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach this is by writing a subquery to assign an ordered [row number](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) by customer ID, which you can then use to filter on.

```
SELECT ID
    , Email
    , Customer_FirstName
    , Status
    , RecordTimeStamp
FROM (      
SELECT ID
    , Email
    , Customer_FirstName
    , Status
    , RecordTimeStamp
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY RecordTimeStamp DESC) as ID_Row
FROM CustomerSourceDE
) as A
WHERE ID_Row = 1
```